# Scrape all Text on a Webpage that is buried within Tags in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I need to scrape a webpage (https://www304.americanexpress.com/credit-card/compare) but I am running into an issue -- the text that I need on the front page is absolutely buried within many different formatting tags.

I know how to scrape a regular page using Beautiful Soup but this is not giving me what I want (i.e. text is missing, some tags make it through...)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import Counter


urls = ['https://www304.americanexpress.com/credit-card/compare']

with open('thisisanew.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
    for url in urls:
        website = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(website.content)
        text = [''.join(s.findAll(text=True))for s in soup.findAll('p')]
        for item in text:
            print (''.join([element.text for element in soup.body.find_all(lambda tag: tag != 'script', recursive=False)]))
```

Is there a special way to scrape this particular webpage?

Comment: Use your browser's developer tools. The text you're looking for is probably loaded via AJAX.

Comment: can you remove `scrapy` from the tags? The question has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a regular webpage. For instance `<span class="card-offer-des">` contains the text `after you use your new Card to make $1,000 in purchases within the first 3 months.`. I also tried turning off Javascript in the browser. The text is still there as it should be.

So I don't really see what the problem is. Also, I would suggest that try to learn lxml and xpath. Once you know how that works, it's actually easier to get the text you want.

Comment: you are right -- I guess the actual problem for me is how to eliminate everything BUT the text since there is so much formatting going on!  I will reword and apologies for my unobservance

Comment: You can do that quite easily in lxml (which is a python library) :).

Comment: is it used alongside BS or is it it's own scraper?  Sorry, actually never used it!

Comment: Read this [presentation](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1MK60gx8mGTkrTurUSnQZVgwq3ufHe02-Dg6rfqVT3gg) I wrote not too long ago.

Answer (score 0):

The code you should try with python is:

```
if not "what-have-you" in StringPulledFromSite: continue;
if "what-have-you" in StringPulledFromSite:
[your code to save to the filesystem];
```

And the string you should aim for would be something like:

```
((<span class=\") && (/>))
```

you should try to find both (and attempt to be specific, so that you can easily differentiate from them). Once you've found both, save the string, test it and save the text.